# Display element in form using Zurb Foundation

Tags: zurb-foundation

I'm using the [CSS Framework Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/forms.php) and when I write the following code:

```
<div class="row">    
   <div class="two mobile-one columns"><label for="invoiceterm-summary" class="right inline">Become late <span class="required">*</span></label></div>
   <div class="ten mobile-three columns"><input class="one" id="invoiceterm-late" name="invoiceterm[late]" type="text" value=""> days after invoice sent</div>
</div>
​
```

I get this :

[image]

But I want to display the text **"days after invoice sent"** like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to remove the display: block property from the css definition of the input[type="text"] on the foundation.css file

Answer (score 0):

You should place all of these elements into a single:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="twelve mobile-four columns"></div>
</div>
```

Otherwise it is behaving correctly, stacking the columns as the screen size is reduced.